# idea git nothing to revert and commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-commit, git-revert

os:mac 10.11.5

ide:idea 2016

in idea , i write some code , then i want to commit it .

use command line

```
git status
```

show me

```
On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:

modified:   src/main/java/config/Demo1.java
```

it's ok,i can commit my code and push it.

but i use idea's git plugins commit show me

> nothing to commit,no changes detected

use revert ,also show me

> nothing to revert,no changes detected

how do I fix it,thanks

Comment: Do you have git set up in preferences -> version control?

Comment: "Changes not staged for commit:" - There was nothing to commit. You have to stage them first.

Comment: `git add` the changed file that you want to commit

Comment: Right click the file -> `Git` -> `Add`

Comment: Thank you . I have solved this problem. 
in idea , my project Unregistered Vcs root detected The directory . So some integrated version control features that will not be able to function.